# Dimension error when merge Embedding layer and Input layer in keras

Tags: python, merge, keras, embedding, lstm

i am trying to merge the output of two embedding layer and one input layer. The code are as follows.

```
    maxlen = 200
    nFactor = 10

    input1 = Input((maxlen, len(chars)))
    e1 = Input((maxlen, 1))
    e2 = Input((maxlen, 1))
    em1 = Embedding(nUser, nFactor + 1, input_length=maxlen)(e1)
    em2 = Embedding(nItem, nFactor + 1, input_length=maxlen)(e2)

    print(input1._keras_shape)
    print(em1._keras_shape)
    print(em2._keras_shape)

    merged = merge([input1, em1, em2], mode='concat',concat_axis=2)
    print(merged._keras_shape)
```

However, I met the problem at the merge step. I've printed the shape of input1, em1 and em2, all these three are 3D tensors. So I am not sure why there is still a join problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
    (None, 200, 98)
    (None, 200, 11)
    (None, 200, 11)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "test.py", line 96, in <module>
        merged = merge([input1, em1, em2,], mode='concat',concat_axis=2)
    File "/home/.../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 1680, in merge
        name=name)
    ...
    TypeError: Join() can only join tensors with the same number of dimensions.
```

Comment: Have you tried 'concat_axis=-1' ?

Comment: Yes, I've tried concat_axis=-1 but it still failed. Here I want to concatenate on the last dimension, which means I want to get a new vector as (None, 200,98+11+11).

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed that. I changed the embedding input as (maxlen,) rather than (maxlen,1)...